# Inequality in Frankl's conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, conjectures

For the minimal counter-example to union closed sets conjecture, we have the lower bound $\mid$$\mathcal{A}$$\mid$ $\geq$ $4q-1$ ($\mathcal{A}$ denotes the minimal counter-example family, $q$ denotes the number of elements in $\cup$$\mathcal{A}$). Is there any better lower bound? Is there any research/development happening towards this direction?

Comment: There is quite a bit of information at the [Polymath wiki](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Frankl%27s_union-closed_conjecture) on Frankl's conjecture.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks. But, under the section 'Partial results', it states the same inequality '$n$ $\leq$ $4m-2$, assuming $\mathcal{A}$ is separating'. So, of not much help in this particular direction.

Comment: Which suggests that as of March 2016, when the page was last updated, no better bound was known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2018 paper [A lower bound for the minimal counter-example to Frankl’s conjecture by Ankush Hore](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/72/ajc_v72_p350.pdf) improved the bound to:
$$\mid\mathcal{A}\mid \geq 4q+1$$